# Cancelling a jQuery transition based on browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, media, transition

At the moment I have a simple jQuery transition that goes as such:

```
$('#container').delay(600).fadeIn('slow'),
```

My question is how I would cancel out this transition based on what the browser size is, somewhat like a CSS media query?

Comment: Can you explain more in detail, what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable with `jquery` then you can try this :

```
if($(window).width() > 600) //here instead of '600' you can give your required width
{
   $('#container').delay(600).fadeIn('slow')
}
else
{
   ......
}
```

Comment: @kkslider..i think above answer will solve your problem if need more help then plz comment..thanks..

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am somewhat comfortable with jQuery, but I still have a lot to learn. I added your code and when I specify the size that I want, the div doesn't even appear. However any size larger than specifies follows through with the animation. What I'm looking to achieve is to have the container appear without any transition on the mobile version of my site.

Comment: @kkslider....the thing you are telling that with above code div is not even showing this should not happen just check if there is some thing giving problem there or you can specify $('#container').show() in else statement..

Comment: Nevermind, your code did work. I forgot about a display:none I was using to hide #container. Thanks a lot.